# How to stack and insert columns into rows in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to write a macro to get the result as shown in the figure below:

From:  To:

abc.a@xxx.com aaa.b@xxx.com,bbb.a@xxx.com

I want it in this form:

From     To

aaa.a     aaa.b

aaa.a     bbb.a

But the Macro code(described below) writes everything under column 'A', which I don't want.
Please help me to correct the following Macro code so that I get the result as in the image shown.

Macro Code:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long
Dim wsDATA As Worksheet, wsNEW As Worksheet

Set wsDATA = ActiveSheet
Set wsNEW = Sheets.Add
LR = wsDATA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Rw = 2 To LR
    wsDATA.Rows(Rw).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy
    wsNEW.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Next Rw
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    Application.Run "'email headers.csv'!Macro2"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "First.Last@company.com"
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A8").Select

End Sub
```

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Comment: have you had any chance to review my suggestion?

Comment: hi David, sorry.. could not log  in to Stackoverflow and hence, could not review your solution. But, thank you very much for your help. Would work it out now. Thank you once again.

Comment: Cheers. Glad I could assist you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code is attempting to paste the data in the next available *row* of column A:

```
wsNEW.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
```

What you want to do is find the next available *column* in row 1 (presumably), and paste there, and since you're not transposing, you can omit that parameter (or set it to False, which is the default.

Assuming you're starting with an empty worksheet:

```
For Rw = 2 To LR
    wsDATA.Rows(Rw).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy
    wsNEW.Cells(1, Rw-1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
Next Rw
```

Assuming you're starting with a sheet which may contain data already, and that row 1 is a reasonably proxy for whether any particular column has data:

```
For Rw = 2 To LR
    wsDATA.Rows(Rw).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy
    wsNEW.Cells(1, wsNew.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
Next Rw
```